# Glitch when rendering in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Its really weird, One side of the render has this weird line, I cut out a part of my drone render to show you. What could be the reason for this? I am rendering on Cycles. Checked the cad and it is fine, imported in in FBX to keep colors from fusion 360. I even re-mirored the weird arm in fusion but still same problem

[image]

Comment: The most probable is that you have 2 objects overlapping and creating artifacts. Consider uploading your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but it's most likely the result of two overlapping meshes. You can join them together with the boolean modifier to fix this.

If that doesn't work, recalculate the normals of your meshes.